# What is the amplitude and phase of this following equation?

Tags: waves

Suppose I have two waves 
$$\begin{align}
\psi(1) &= A\sin(kx-\omega t) \\
\psi(2) &= A\sin\{(k+\Delta k)x-(\omega+\Delta\omega)t\}
\end{align}$$

and due to superposition

$$\begin{align}
\psi &= \psi(1) + \psi(2) \\
     &= 2 \cos \left(\frac{\Delta kx}{2} - \frac{\Delta\omega t}{2}\right)
        \sin \left\{\left(k+\frac{\Delta k}{2}\right)x-\left(\omega+\frac{\Delta\omega}{2}\right)t\right\}
\end{align}$$
Now my question is what is the new amplitude and phase of the above equation and how?

Comment: I think your final equation should have an extra $A$ in it.

Answer (score 0):

if $\Delta k \ll k$ and $\Delta\omega \ll \omega$, then the cosine doesn't change much over the period of sine, so you can interpret $2\cos(...)$ as modulated amplitude and $\sin(...)$ as a periodic function.

**Edit:**
The general wave doesn't have definite amplitude and phase. That is the property of sine and cosine, and general wave is simply superposition of many waves with given amplitude and phase. You can find which ones by Furier transform.

But sometimes, as in your case, one can write the wave in the form 
$$
\psi (x,t)=A(x,t)\sin{\left(kx+\omega t \right)}
$$
where $A(x,t)$ does not change much over one period of sine. Then, if you plot only few periods, the function $\psi (x,t)$ still looks pretty similar to sine, so it makes sense to define period as period of this sine function, where the amplitude is slowly changing:
[image]

Or when you take more periods you get something like this:
 [image]

Comment: Yeah my book says something like that. Can you explain it a bit please?

Comment: i tried in the edit, check it out

Answer (score 0):

Not all waves have a well definited amplitude, frequency and phase. These are properties of sines and cosines only, and can not be generalised to a general superposition. In your example $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$ are plane waves with a well defined frequency and amplitude, but $\psi$ is a superposition of the two waves. The only thing one can say about $\psi$, is that it is a superposition of two waves with well defined amplitudes and phase.

If not all waves have well defined amplitudes and phases, then why do we care so much about such concepts? The answer is Fourier analysis. It tells that any (well behaved) function can be expressed as a sum of sines and cosines. Therefore, we can think of any wave as a superposition of plane waves (sine and cosines) interfering with each other.